# How to post data as json from request payload?

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs

Here is my code sample, though i set the method as post it will set Request Method to OPTIONS and request payload won't be set.

i am not sure this is a problem with CORS since it is working with chrome plugging such as Postman and Rest Console. i have checked both tools requested to server is request method:post, Content-Type:applicaion/json and data in $scope.data will be set to request payload. what would be the reason?

```
angular.module('httpExample', []).controller('FetchController', ['$scope', '$http', '$templateCache',
function($scope, $http, $templateCache) {
$scope.headers= {
                'Accept': '*/*',
                'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=UTF-8'
            };
            $scope.method = 'POST';
            $scope.url = 'http://localhost:56652/reqresp.svc/json/post';
            $scope.data={"requests":[{"__type":"AuthenticateAndGetProsties:#LabOra.ProsteModul.ReqResp.Requests", "Authentication":{ "__type":"UserAuthentication:#LabOra.ProsteModul.ReqResp","Username":"xxx","Password":"yyyy" }}]};

            $scope.fetch = function() {
                $scope.code = null;
                $scope.response = null;

                $http({method: $scope.method, url: $scope.url,data: JSON.stringify($scope.data),headers:$scope.headers, cache: $templateCache}).
                    success(function(data,status) {
                        $scope.status = status;
                        //$scope.data =x2js.xml_str2json(data);
                        $scope.data =data;
                    }).
                    error(function( status) {
                        $scope.data = "Request failed";
                        $scope.status = status;
                    });
            };
        }]);
})(window.angular);
```

Comment: For cross-origin POST and PUT requests (and maybe others), your browser will first send an OPTIONS request to check CORS availability. If you're not seeing a POST after that, then it failed for some reason. Everything you need to debug the problem should be available in your developer consoles.

Comment: and you can receive data from a non CORS enabled api but browser will reject access to that data and throw an ajax error instead

Comment: Yes, actually it was cors issue and agatha rest service did not enable cors.   Thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was CORS issue and Agatha rest service did not enable CORS. what you have to do to enable CORS in agatha is put following configurations in global.asax.cs

```
        // enable CORS
        response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
        response.AddHeader("X-Frame-Options", "ALLOW-FROM *");

        if (context.Request.HttpMethod == "OPTIONS")
        {
            response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Request-Method", "POST,GET,PUT,DELETE,OPTIONS");
            response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Accept");
            response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Authorization,Origin,X-Requested-With,Content-Type");
            response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Max-Age", "1728000");
            response.End();
        }
```

Enjoy...!!!